# isRecognitionAvailable return false on android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm using the android.speech.SpeechRecognizer on Android.
In some cases, isRecognitionAvailable return false, so I can't recognize the speech.
Is there no way to enable android.speech.SpeechRecognizer on Phone?
Or is there similar service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this) returns false your device has no SpeechRecognizer support. Is simple.

Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If isRecognitionAvailable return false, can't use android.speech.recognizer forever?

Comment: With the device you are trying no, try with other.

Answer (score 5):

I know that it has passed too much time but this may help somebody.

I run into a very strange issue. I knew that speech recognizer once worked in my Android 5.1.1 phone. However, isRecognitionAvailable started to return false. However, createSpeechRecognizer was creating the object (although it didnt start listening). It was strange because according to documentation:

> isRecognitionAvailable:
>
> Checks whether a speech recognition service is available on the
>   system. If this method returns false, createSpeechRecognizer(Context)
>   will fail.

I ended up going into PlayStore and looking for "Ok google" and I found that Google LLC was disabled. I enabled it and Speech Recognizer started to work again.

Hope this helps anyone

Comment: On Samsung S9 one can disable the Google application, and that will in turn disable the STT service. Found out the hard way. Great catch @mgonzalez

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no way to enable android.speech.SpeechRecognizer on Phone? Or is there similar service ?

No, `SpeechRecognizer` is a **SYSTEM** service. If it is not available, then there is not such  service on the device. Here is the quote from documentation.

> Checks whether a speech recognition service is available on the **system**.

If you really want speech recognition, you can record the mic input and process the raw input yourself.

Comment: Hi Joshua,
Thanks for your reply.
If isRecognitionAvailable return false, can't use android.speech.recognizer forever?

Comment: @danielparker Yes, it is device specific. You have nothing to do about it unless you row your own. You can disable that functionality for those devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting API 30 or higher, add the following to manifest file, outside application block:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```